# vmware kills host's network connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, vmware

I'm using vwware 9 with Windows 8(guest) on ubuntu 13.04(host) with network set to NAT. It perfectly works when I'm on wifi. But whenever I try using wired ethernet, it stops working.

So, it looks like that: I have a connection, Internet is accessible, everything's fine, I start VM in vwmare player, Windows sees connection, internet is accessible from within the guest for like 3-5 seconds, and then suddenly neither guest nor host can see internet anymore. And only thing I can do is to disable networking and re-enable it again and wait it to be killed again.

I need to fix that asap, please help

ps: both host and guest settings set to dhcp. firewall on guest machine is disabled. vmware tools are installed. Switching to bridged connection ain't helping

Comment: What are the results from ipconfig(Windows) and ifconfig(Ubuntu)? If you have enough time, run these commands in that short time before the connection cuts out.

Answer (score 1):

I looks I found the problem:

I opened adapter properties on Windows and disabled these:

- Deterministic Network Enhancer
- QoS packet scheduler
- Microsoft Multiplexor protocol
- LLDP Driver
- Discovery Driver and Discovery responder
  and even IPv6

seems one of them a culprit, exactly which one yet has to be determined (can't do that right now)

Comment: What is **Deterministic Network Enhancer**?